# qsort in c not sorting my array of structs

Tags: c, qsort

I'm having an issue with my comparison function for qsort. I've got an array, mGames, of type ListEntry. ListEntry looks like this:

```
struct ListEntry
{
    bool mLocal;
    int  mLastTurnTime;
};
```

That's actually rather oversimplified, there's more data in there but it's not being used in the sorting so I omitted it. Anyway, I'm trying to make it so that entries that have mLocal set to true are ordered first. Problem is, I can't get qsort to order my array whatsoever. Here's the comparison function:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    ListEntry* e1 = (ListEntry*)a;
    ListEntry* e2 = (ListEntry*)b;
    if (e1->mLocal && e2->mLocal)
        return 0;
    return e1->mLocal ? -1 : 1;
}
```

and my call to it:

```
qsort(mGames, mNumGames, sizeof(ListEntry), compare);
```

where mNumGames is the number of games in the array (7 in my current test case), and mGames is defined as:

```
ListEntry mGames[MAX_GAMES]; // where MAX_GAMES is 50
```

When I step into the compare method, e1 and e2 contain their data as expected (as in, I'm not accessing garbage memory or didn't dereference things right).

The weird thing is, no matter how I change that comparison method, I can't get the order to change at all. I must be overlooking something really obvious.

Comment: Is the by-value assignment in your comparator accidental? You should not dereference the pointer but assign the result of the cast to another pointer. And I guess we need more code.

Comment: Ah, good call. I've changed it in my code to just use the pointer value and not be dereferenced.

Comment: By the way, is this C (tag, use of qsort) or C++ (no struct keyword in variable declaration, bool, cast of void pointer)? In the former case it must be some strange extensions (I know C99 has bool, but direct struct usage without struct keyword?) and in the latter case, don't use `qsort` anyway, use `std::sort`.

Answer (score 4):

Your function is not a partial ordering. This

```
if (e1.mLocal && e2.mLocal)
    return 0;
```

should be in fact

```
if (e1.mLocal == e2.mLocal)
```

The point is, once you deal with `qsort` (and other sorting routines as well, you need to ensure the comparison relation is transitive and antisymmetric. That wouldn't be true in your case.

BTW, since you effectively sort only in two classes, it might be faster just to move the elements with `.mLocal == 1` to the beginning of the array by something like

```
ListEntry *first = beginning of the array, *last = end of the array;
while(first < last) {
  if(!first->mLocal && last->mLocal)
    swap(first, last); // swap the two elements
  if(first->mLocal) first++;
  if(!last->mLocal) last --;
}
```

Comment: Ah, so it turns out the main problem was that I wasn't updating where my list elements were to be drawn at AFTER I had qsort them: I forgot that I was assigning where they appear on screen before the qsort. Turns out that was the real gist of the problem, though thanks for everyone's suggestions here, those were also part of a larger problem.